# TypeError: unsupported operand type for NoneType and str

Tags: python, string, typeerror, nonetype

I am a new programming student so I'm sure it's just something I'm over looking but I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/anonymous/Documents/sales with a list.py", line 11, in <module>
    print("Sales store ") + str(count + 1) + " " + locale.currency(sales[count], grouping = True)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

This is the code I am trying to run:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, ' ') 

sales = [0.0] * 5
totalSales = float(0.0)
for count in range(5):
    sales[count] = float(input("Enter store sales amount: "))
    totalSales = float(totalSales) + float(sales[count])
for count in range(5):
    print("Sales store ") + str(count + 1) + " " + locale.currency(sales[count], grouping = True)
print("Total Sales of all stores " + locale.currency(totalSales, grouping = True))
```

Comment: You may want to edit your error message to omit your full name from the file path and replace it with a dummy name.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to concatenate the return value of `print` with some strings. Try this instead:

```
print("Sales store " + str(count + 1) + " " + locale.currency(sales[count], grouping = True))
```

The difference is on the first `print`. In your initial code, you close the paren after "Sales store" immediately. `print` returns None, so your code is equivalent to:

```
None + str(count + 1) + " " + locale.currency(sales[count], grouping=True)
```

The replacement version instead builds one big string as a single argument for `print`.